Templating the request message in Airflow GrpcOperator
Airflow's GrpcOperator supports passing template variables in the data field. However, the protobuf-generated message object that needs to go into the data field is evaluated at parse time, which breaks the templates.
For example, in the task below, I want to send a request to a gRPC server that has the DAG run's date ds in its message body:
task_grpc = GrpcOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="task_grpc",
    grpc_conn_id="grpc_default",
    stub_class=CustomGrpcServiceStub,
    call_func="CustomGrpcServiceFunction",
    response_callback=CustomGrpcService_callback,
    streaming=False,
    data = {"request": proto_pb2.CustomGrpcServiceRequest(request_date="{{ ds }}")}
)

This will fail, as the request_date is always rendered as "{ ds }". Is there a workaround to achieve templated fields in the protobuf message objects?
I tried to write a user-defined macro as suggested in https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/36661, but that does not change the outcome.

By implementing a custom operator it is possible to supply the data for GrpcOperator at execute time (instead of init time). All templated variables (in this case just request_date) can be put into the constructor of the custom operator while being added to the sequence of template_fields. At execute time, the templated variables can then be used to assemble the data object.
For the given example, the custom operator is
class CustomGrpcServiceRequestOperator(GrpcOperator):
    template_fields: Sequence[str] = tuple({"request_date"} | set(GrpcOperator.template_fields))

    def __init__(self, request_date: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.request_date = request_date


    def execute(self, context: Context):
        self.data = {
            "request": proto_pb2.CustomGrpcServiceRequest(request_date=self.request_date)
            }
        super().execute(context)

which can then be called as
task_grpc = CustomGrpcServiceRequestOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="task_grpc",
    grpc_conn_id="grpc_default",
    stub_class=CustomGrpcServiceStub,
    call_func="CustomGrpcServiceFunction",
    response_callback=CustomGrpcService_callback,
    streaming=False,
    request_date="{{{{ ds }}}}"
)

